# Finding the space of solutions of a single equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, systems-of-equations

If the equation is $$3x+3y+2z=0$$

How would you be able to determine a vector/pair of vectors which describes the space of solutions?

I'm quite new to linear algebra so apologies if this is a very dumb question.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  I can tell by eye-balling that $(1,-1,0)$ and $(0,2,-3)$ are solutions

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but how would one work this out?

Comment: You could write the general solution vector as $(x,y,z)=(x,y,-3(x+y)/2)=x(1,0,-3/2)+(0,1,-3/2)$

Comment: @ShubhamJohri; You're missing a $y$ in the decomposition.

Comment: @Bernard Thanks. Can't fix it now tho But the OP should have the idea.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for vectors perpendicular to $(3,3,2)$.

Two are $(3,3,2)\times(0,0,1)$ and $(3,3,2)\times(1,0,0)$.

They are linearly independent and span the space of solutions.